# Culture-specific sorting not applied when deployed

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, locale, cultureinfo

I have a List of objects and need to sort the list based on one of the properties. This sorting should be done based on a specified culture. I found many resources explaining how this could be achieved and implemented them with success locally. However, when I deploy the code, sorting does not appear to be done based on the specified culture.

I have tried using both LINQ's OrderBy and List's Sort, both with the overload which accepts a StringComparer.

These are the snippets:

```
nor = norwegianStrings.OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.Create(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("no-NO", true), true)).ToArray();
```

```
danishStrings.Sort(StringComparer.Create(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK"), true));
```

Both of these are working locally, and for reference I have tried both Array and List. When deployed though, it just sorts normally, like InvariantCulture. I have also tried to manually set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and then using that in the StringComparer.

I have tried to add the cultures in Startup via

```
    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[] { "no-NO", "sv-SE", "da-DK" };
        options.SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
               .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
               .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
    });
```

I am at a loss. Any idea why this could be happening? How can I solve this, or troubleshoot further?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are those cultures available on the target machine?

Comment: i would guess so, but I can include some more details regarding the machine
- It's a web app hosted on Azure, in a container running on Linux. Region is North Europe. 

How can I check whether they are available?

Comment: If the relevant locale data isn't installed on the deployment target, you may need to ship your app with [App-local ICU](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu#app-local-icu). I had a similar problem once with various locales not being installed on CI servers running Windows Server which would work locally on Windows 10/11.

Comment: The dockerfile is supposed to take care of the ICU with `RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs`. 
Now trying App-local ICU approach as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was indeed regarding locales available in the machine.

App-local ICU was a no-go, or at least I was unable to get my container up and running with it.
The dockerfile already included `RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs`, but I did find that in some distros, icu-libs only included english locales.
So, I also had to include `RUN apk add --no-cache icu-data-full`.

Nothing required in Program.cs or Startup.cs. Nothing required in .csproj, just make sure to include the CORRECT icu in the machine.

Thanks for the help, guys!